# Expect function bash

Tags: bash, expect

I'm trying to do a bash script with expect in this style :

```
spawn etc 
expect "something"
send -- "something " 
etc
```

But I would like to do

```
send -- function()
```

How is this possible ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the output of a `bash` function as an argument of the `send` command/instruction? I do not know `spaw`, `send` and `etc` commands... Is it actually an `expect` script instead of a `bash` script?

Answer (score 2):

bash and expect are different languages, and expect cannot magically reach into its parent to grab some code.

However, if you *export* the function, you can (eventually) use it:

bash: define the function

```
$ function foo { echo bar; }
$ foo
bar
```

fail to export it, try to use it

```
$ expect
expect1.1> foo
invalid command name "foo"
    while executing
"foo"
expect1.2> exec bash -c foo
bash: foo: command not found
    while executing
"exec bash -c foo"
expect1.3> exit
```

now, export the function

```
$ export -f foo
$ expect
expect1.1> exec bash -c foo
bar
```

Now, you can do this:

```
send -- "[exec bash -c your_function]\r"
```

But the key is: **export the function while in the parent shell.**